# Email Template not working properly on Outlook App

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I have created a email signature (HTML template). That works perfectly fine on outlook web, Gmail and other clients but fails on Microsoft Outlook (Mail) App. I am using the following code:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<span style="font-family: Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-size: 16px !important; letter-spacing: 0px; color: #3e3e3e; margin-left: 0px;">Charlotte McMahon</span>
<br>
<span style="font-family: Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 700; font-size: 12px !important; letter-spacing: 0px; text-transform: uppercase; color: #3e3e3e; line-height: 20px; margin-left: 0px;">
    Head of Block Management
</span>
<br>
<img src="https://hawkblockmanagement.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Hawk-Logo.png" alt="Hawk Block Management" style="width: 150px; margin: 10px 0 20px 0;"><br>
<span style="font-family: Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-size: 10px !important; letter-spacing: 1px; color: #3e3e3e !important; text-transform: uppercase; line-height: 20px; margin-left: 0px;">
    <strong>DD:</strong> 
    <a href="tel:02080161178" style="color: #3e3e3e !important; text-decoration:none !important;">020 8016 1178</a>
</span><br/>
<span style="font-family: Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-size: 10px !important; letter-spacing: 1px; color: #3e3e3e !important; text-transform: uppercase; line-height: 20px; margin: 0px 10px 0 0;">
    <strong>T:</strong> 
    <a href="tel:02080164122" style="color: #3e3e3e !important; text-decoration:none !important; text-decoration:none;">020 8016 4122</a>
</span>
<br>
<span style="font-family: Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-size: 10px !important; letter-spacing: 1px; color: #3e3e3e !important; text-transform: uppercase; line-height: 20px; margin-left: 0px;">
    <strong>E:</strong>
    <a href="mailto:cmcmahon@hawkbm.com" target="_blank" style="color: #3e3e3e !important; text-decoration:none !important; text-decoration:none;">cmcmahon@hawkbm.com</a>
</span><br>
<span style="font-family: Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-size: 10px !important; letter-spacing: 1px; color: #3e3e3e !important; text-transform: uppercase; line-height: 20px; margin-left: 0px;">
    <strong>W:</strong>
    <a title="Hawk Block Management" href="https://hawkbm.com" style="color: #3e3e3e !important; text-decoration:none !important; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank">hawkblockmanagement.com</a></span><br>
    <div style="padding: 10px 0 0 0;"></div>
    <span style="font-family: Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-size: 10px !important; letter-spacing: 1px; color: #3e3e3e !important; text-transform: uppercase; line-height: 15px;;">
        <a title="Map" href="https://goo.gl/maps/mtfqGUtziZD2" style="color: #3e3e3e !important; text-decoration:none !important; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank">Kirkdale House, Kirkdale Road,

            Leytonstone, London E11 1HP</a></span><br>
<img src="https://hawkblockmanagement.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/block2.jpg" alt="Hawk Block Management" style="width: 150px; margin: 20px 0 0 0;">
```

The expected result and result on Outlook, Gmail is

[image]

But the result on Outlook App is

[image]

Is there any solution to make design consistent on Outlook Mail App too?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook tends to ignore inline style image sizes. Add `width="150"` which will correct Outlook growing. Outlook will ignore margins placed on the image. Add a padding to the table cell instead.

```
<img src="https://hawkblockmanagement.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Hawk-Logo.png" width="150" alt="Hawk Block Management" style="width: 150px; height: auto;">
```

Outlook doesn't support Montserrat. It doesn't work with webfonts, so it's using Arial as it's fallback. This is risky because it might default to Times New Roman, making everything serif.

Good luck.